# Resolve the citations but do not include the list of references

Tags: bibtex, citing

I need to prepare a separate abstract file without the list of references. However, I do have some citations in the abstract and I want them to be resolved, but without producing the list of refs in the end. Is there any solution?

Thanks
- Baskaran

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: i do hope you're using a bibliography style that provides more than just a number or a key.  those are most uninformative without suitable context.

Comment: A decidedly low-tech way to go is to place the `\bibliography{somebibfile}` at the very end of the document (starting on a new page) and to leave off the page(s) taken up by the bibliography...

Comment: @Mico: yeah that's what I did so far. Heiko's solution solved it.

Comment: @barbara: yeah, my style gives the name of the first author and year and so it is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard LaTeX writes the data of `\bibitem` via `\immediate\write` into the `.aux` file. This allows putting the bilbiography in a box that is never used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World \cite{foobar}.

\begin{lrbox}{0}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foobar} Foo bar.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]